# 8/16/32/64 bit aligned lossless compression of .bss and .data for embedded system core dump

Tags: compression, alignment, coredump, sparc, lossless

I'm looking for a fast / lossless / fix spaced compression algorithm for the following task.

I have an embedded system. Low memory / flash resource.

I want to generate a core dump for it and store the result in flash and / or suck it out over a slow serial line.

All I need essentially is the heap, stack, .data and .bss segments and a few memory mapped registers.

The device is a Leon Sparc Softcore.

Now this data as a couple of oddities which indicate that

1. The usual LZW / Zlib / ... compression libraries won't do as well. (Not a natural language corpus).
2. Sparcs are obsessive about alignment. ie. I can guarantee that *every* item in the .bss and .data segments is either (effectively) an 8, 16, 32 or 64 bit int aligned correspondingly at 8,16,32,64 bit address boundaries.
3. I'd have to reserve a small fixed space for the compression code.
4. It's a 32 bit machine with the size of the bss and data segments very much smaller than 4gb.
5. Most 32 bit values in the system are addresses of symbols. ie. A very very small subset of the 4 gig possible values.

My current plan is to...
Scan the entire .bss / .data segments and compute a complete histogram for 16 bit values.

From this I can get a perfect huffman encoding. But I suspect I can do a lot better contemplating the internal structure of 32 bit / 64 bit values. (eg. The variability in the most significant half of bits is much much much less than the variability of the least significant bits.)

And pointers / suggestions / existing work?